# Good places to shop for paleo diet?

Tags: paleo-diet

Do you have any recommendations on good places to shop to get paleo diet meals/ingredients?

My status as of today: I don't shop much, and I barely cook. Premade meals are neat, and so are stores where I don't have to worry about reading every single label.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question so that it is less of a shopping recommendation specific to north Jersey? We try to avoid those two types of questions. What is your specific situation, and what problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: My specific situation is: I want to use the paleo diet. I want to minimize the pain of shopping for the paleo diet. What if I just removed the location and said I was in the US instead?

Comment: It's my understanding, though I can't find an authoritative reference, that shopping-recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann if they are off-topic, where will they be on-topic?

Comment: A tweet to @robbwolf? I don't know, man. :)

Comment: Okay, now assume I'm just asking about nutrition shopping questions that aren't about the paleo diet. Where would THOSE questions be on-topic? I'm curious. I would like those questions answered, and I will go where they will be answered.

Comment: I don't know. Try asking in meta.fitness.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I think the most effective strategy for the average person is to shop for their lean meats and veggies on a day that you have off work and prepare a large number of meals upfront and freeze some. To meet the minimum requirement for Paleo you can buy good ingredients at your local supermarket. If you want to go a little more down the proverbial rabbit hole you can buy grass-fed beef and bison as well as free-range chicken and wild caught fish. Check the web for local farmers' markets as well. It is unlikely that we will ever find convenient pre-made meals in our supermarkets that are Paleo as the higher degree of processing required would take such meals out of line with the dietary philosophy. For small snacks you can combine dried fruits (no added sugar), unsalted nuts, and jerky.

All that being said their are services out there that you can find. It might take some searching on Google or networking. My wife, for example, prepares Paleo meals for a few people I work with. We do lunch-hour crossfit sessions and many of the participants are Paleo eaters. So you might find someone like that who could shop and prepare the meals for you. She charges $5.00 per meal (but it's just for the people I work with, sorry!).

Here are some links for you that might help:

http://www.paleobrands.com/

http://www.paleoplan.com/resources/sampler-menu-meal-plan/

http://robbwolf.com/2011/01/16/pre-cooking-paleo-diet-food/

Comment: Well, that paleobrands website is amazing. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I think you should edit your question and make it a little more generic about preparing Paleo meals with a sports nutrition slant. That way we can ask the question be re-opened.